# Conditional actions when an Oracle APEX navigation bar item is click

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

The application has a Home item in the navigation bar (the item is in all the pages). I would like that when the home item is clicked, based upon the page number a warning box is shown to the user warning them, that all unsaved work will be lost. If the user presses yes, he or she will be taken to the application home page and nothing will be saved. If they press no, he or she will stay in the page.

Currently this dialog box shows up in every page. In Oracle Application Express, `shared components > navigation bar > target area`,  these are my settings:

Target type = `url`

URL target =

```
javascript:if(confirm('All unsaved work will be lost?')) 
{window.location.href ='f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.:&APP_PAGE_ID.';}
```

I would like this behavior to only occur in a select number of pages. When a user clicks on the pages not included in this list, the warning box should not be shown and the user is taken to the application home page.

Answer (score 1):

What you'd want is a dynamic action which targets the navigation bar entries. However, there is simply no easy way to selectively enable or disable this action on select items save for testing the text of the anchor tag. That would mean you'd be hardcoding values in your dynamic action to test the links, which i will not recommend. 
There are no classes that can be assigned, and no onclick events.
You could use the code you posted, and have a javascript function which takes a page id as input parameter and then checks the page id against a list of pages which allow the action, but again complicated. It could be made dynamic with some ajax, but since you're unfamiliar with javascript it's better to first get accustomed with it before tackling that.
So, instead of inventing something like this, take a look at this [save before exit plugin](http://apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/dynamic-action-plugin/skillbuilders-save-before-exit_43.html). It will check for unsaved changes, and you can add this just to the pages you want it on.